# Fixing Finder Folder Disply

Tags: finder, display, folders

So first you'll need to forgive me for the lack of proper terminology. My problem is this, when I open a finder window, and navigate down past the 3rd layer of folders, and then want to open the folder I am in, in a new tab, as the first folder row, or main tab window, all I am getting in the new tab is the folder tree that I have open in the existing tab replicated.

[image: This image shows the main directory]

[image: New directory level, standard enough stuff]

[image: The Problem]

Now it might not be obvious because of how I have cropped the images, but i would expect to right click on the applications folder, open in new tab and expect only the folders inside of the applications folder to be listed, but they are not, both previous folder trees remain open. I expect it is something simple. But can somebody help me fix this please? I have Mojave 10.14.1

Comment: you might want to use other views in view menu..